# Configuration of 2 Bitbucket accounts on one laptop: cannot clone code

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, capistrano

I have 2 bitbucket's accounts - one for work, one personal.

Defaultly I am using the working account, but now needed to clone some code from a repository under the person account and got this error:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:my_personal/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
repository access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I generated new set of keys on my laptop for the personal Bitbucket account - `personal` and `personal.pub`. I added this `personal` key to the SSH Account Settings on the personal BB account.

Then, I have set the `/Users/adam/.ssh/config` file:

```
# Work account
Host bitbucket.org
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User my_working_bb_id
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Personal account
Host bitbucket.org_personal
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User personal_bb_id
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
```

I also ran `ssh-add -l`:

```
2048 SHA256:bYwG+K01In4aDtux36u58ywVqhmALTandY4h8yEg7YE /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA) # <- work-account
2048 SHA256:I3FFdzuS1a3oVy2LAgE+Uh3iQfDIYwys24ZMAAwT0B0 /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa_test@gmail.com (RSA)
2048 SHA256:ye3efWFfSt5tOqj7+APV9eU/Q7lquvbJc0GywyuGm68 /Users/adam/.ssh/presonal (RSA)
2048 SHA256:aGsdBd6lqTqRBXuusvblyUbM9d7Hc5+oJNdVgUwumIM /Users/adam/.ssh/presonal (RSA)
```

When I run `ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org`, I get:

> logged in as my_work_bb_id.

I suspect here (above) might be the problem? On my laptop I am still logged in only with my work-BB ID?

Or where is the problem? I am fighting with this issue all afternoon, but cannot move on.

I'll be grateful for every advice!

Answer (score 1):

If you have two separate entries in your ~/.ssh/config file, then you should be able to clone as your personal user with `git clone bitbucket.org_personal:owner/repo.git`.  You should also be able to clone, push, and pull with your own username instead of "git" or "hg" (something like `git clone my_personal_username@bitbucket.org:owner/repo.git`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have more keys, you should use `IdentitiesOnly yes` in your configuration file. It will avoid using the default keys and it will use the keys provided in configuration file as a priority.

Of course you need to clone the way as described in the other answer: use the hostname alias from your ssh configuration:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org_personal:my_personal/project.git
```